# Login with Google OpenID or other providers

Tags: php, openid, google-openid

I am trying to figure out how OpenID works, therefore I am trying to write my own simple class for my web app that uses Google OpenID.

I am wondering if there are any examples that you know, or where I can find some details so I can implement my own class.

I am not looking for a very general class. I need something that will help me write my own implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made good experiences with [lightopenid](http://mewp.s4w.pl/post/17) ([gitorious download](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/raw/master/openid.php)). Unlike two other OpenID libraries I tried for PHP, it was very easy to use, has no external dependencies, is compatible with PHP5 and has no warnings.

There is an [example for using Google](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/example-google.php).

And to display those buttons in the HTML page: http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/